# ast.literal_eval error. ValueError: malformed node or string: <ast.Name object at 0x0000024A165CF7F0>

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

i get data from the game. Sometimes i can use literal_eval, sometimes not. Sometimes it's because i have problems with decode from bytes to str, but this time i dont see.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6LGf.jpg)

Comment: **don't post code/error messages as images or links to images**. Post **all code as formatted text in the question itself**

Comment: Please post it as plain text so we can copy the data and look for problems.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `ast.literal_eval` here? What is the source of this string, exactly? It is quite clearly a JSON. Use `json`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga By changing the case of exactly one letter it's also literal_evalable, so not quite "clearly"...

Comment: Could u share your whole data, on which you applying ast. It will help in testing.

Answer (score 6):

That's JSON, not a Python repr string. (You can tell by the lowercase `false`).

Use `json.loads()` instead of `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: And `print()` always uses single quotes, but JSON uses double quotes.

Comment: this  work nice for me